# Separator below actionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I noticed that most of android applications have a separator under the action bar.
The image below shows the separator:

[image]

How can I use that separator? I thought that this is a default behaviour but in my apps I don't have it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This can be achieved in two ways. By adding a simple line at the top of main content view or a line below the Action bar.(by Customizing background of ActionBar). More prefer to customize ActionBar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in themes.xml,

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@drawable/ab_solid_shadow</item>
```

define the windowContentOverlay attribute. the image is the shadow.

Comment: It works thank you! What's the difference between setting windowsContentOverlay and background?

Comment: what background, is it android:windowBackground?

Comment: I obtain the same results using: 
'''
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
     <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_background</item>
</style>
'''

Comment: <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_background</item> it is the background of the actionbar, windowContentOverlay is below the background.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

windowContentOverlay is drawed by the ActionBarOverLayout(.java), the drawing position is below the actionbar background. the top variable is the height of the actionbar.

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your layout.xml

```
<View
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="0.2dp"
  android:id="@+id/separator"
  android:visibility="visible"
  android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
 />
```